# How to access structure members with structure pointers

Tags: c, structure

I have following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct tag
{
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    struct tag stvar;
    struct tag*stptr=&stvar;

    *(stptr).x=9;

    return 0;
}
```

I could use `stptr->x` but not `*(stptr).x`. I am getting
`request for member 'x' in 'stptr', which is of pointer type 'tag*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)`
Where am i getting it wrong? How to access member with struct pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
*(stptr).x=9;
```

to

```
(*stptr).x=9;
```

The first statement is equivalent to `*(stptr.x)=9;` as postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators. Of course it is better to use the dedicated `->` operator to write this statement:

```
stptr->x=9;
```

Answer (score 1):

In general accessing structure variables can be gone in two ways

```
value.structure_variable; // using (.) operator
```

or

```
( address or pointer )-> structure_variable // using -> operator
```

as ouah pointed out in the answer

```
*(stptr).x=9;
```

is a wrong assignment, on the other hand

(*stptr) is basically the value at address pointer by stptr hence translates to a value thus

```
(*stptr).x=9;
```

is Valid, also since stptr is a pointer itself

```
stptr->x = 9;
```

is harmless , safe and most popular way to assign.